# Find the acceleration of blocks in the elevator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

How to find the acceleration of each block when elevator is accelerating upwards.

Comment: What is on the other side of the right pulley, which has the $2\,\textrm{kg}$ block? Is it attached to the floor of the elevator?

Comment: Start by adding the acceleration of the elevator to "g".

Comment: Yes the other side of the string of 2kg block is attached to the elevator.